# Is there a convention for an SSI comment that doesn't end up in the response?

Tags: nginx, ssi

Since the web server is already parsing for SSI commands, I was thinking it might be nice to have an SSI comment that is processed and discarded from the response, as opposed to an HTML comment that ends up in the response document.

That is:

```
<!-- this is my variable -->
<!--#set var="test" value="DEV" -->
```

has a response document of:

```
<!-- this is my variable -->
```

But if I don't want that in my response document,

```
<!--# discard this from the response document -->
<!--#set var="test" value="DEV" -->
```

Results in a directive processing error (at least on NGINX)

Comment: Just a workaround (or let us better call it a "dirty hack" - that's why I don't want to post it as answer): `<!--#set var="comment_hack" value="this is my variable" -->
<!--#set var="test" value="DEV" -->`